# Time complexity O(n) [C]

Tags: c, time-complexity

I have the following function:

```
void foo(int n){
    int i = 0;
    double temp = 0;


    for (i = 1; i < n ; i++){
        temp = sqrt(i * 1.0);
        if (temp == (int)temp){
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }



}
```

The time complexity is: O(n), is there a way to make the time complexity lower than n?

Comment: if you have to iterate a list it will be O(n) if you have a value you are looking for in a sorted list you can do binary search, in O(*log n) or something like that...

Comment: basically if you have to do this a lot, you can store the answers to sqrt in an array... that would be a better optimization for smallish datasets

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's actually pretty easy considering you only need the squares.

Comment: @EOF I removed my comment as realized it is not what is done here :)

Comment: Looks to me like `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: Obviously, looping over the roots instead of looping over the squares will make it O(sqrt(n)), and it will avoid all the testing, and the possible float-integer comparison failure.

Comment: In this form the complexity is not O(n) but rather n*O(square root computation), and that's above O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this function is searching for perfect squares up to `n`.  Rather than taking the square root of every number up to `n`, you can instead square every number up to `sqrt(n)`:

```
void foo(int n){
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i*i < n ; i++){
        printf("%d ", i*i);
    }
}
```

Not only is this O(sqrt(n)), but it removes floating point operations in the `sqrt` function.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to do in O(sqrt(n)) time [@Lee Daniel Crocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314144/time-complexity-on-c/44314301#comment75633983_44314144), even with no multiplication.

```
void foo_no_multiple(int n) {
  int i = 0;
  int ii = 1;
  while (ii <= n) {
    i++;
    printf("%d ", ii);
    ii += i + i + 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  foo_no_multiple(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 4 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(sqrt(n)).
Simply because instead of looping over `n`, we loop over `sqrt(n)`.

```
void foo(int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    int tmp = 1;
    while (tmp < n)
    {
        printf("%d ", tmp);
        i++;
        tmp = i * i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely due to 1) lack of explanation 2) grammar "If think it's O(sqrt(n))" 3) late similarity to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44314248/2410359) 4) not encapsulated as a function.

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I'm new on stackoverflow and I just want to help people. I'll fix my mistakes.

Comment: @dbush answered it while i was typing, I didn't noticed before i add my answer. Anyway his answer is more elegant than mine.